# Accessing BIOS HP Envy 750-137c

Tags: boot, bios

I'm trying to access the BIOS on my HP Envy 750-137c running Windows 10.  I have tried F2, F8, F10, and F12 along with Esc upon startup, to no avail.  I should be able to get there under Setiings, Update & Security, Advanced Startup, Troubleshoot, and Advanced Settings.  There should be UEFI settings, but it isn't there.  Instead, there is a Startup Options button in its place.  What is happening here?

Comment: Sounds like you are not actually shutting down, but going into "Fast boot" or "fast startup" mode, sometimes called hybrid sleep. Power off, remove A/C and battery and let it sit for a minute or two, then reconnect the battery and A/C and press the power button and rail on ESC and F10, one of those should bring up the menu. If not, pull open the bottom and temporarily remove the hard drive, should be able to access the UEFI/BIOS menu easily then.

Comment: Nothing is working. It's a desktop, so there's no battery to take out.  I unplugged it, restarted and hit esc and f10 (4 or 5 restarts for each).  I did shutdown, restart, I even turned off Fast Startup mode.  Then I went to cmd and ran the "shutdown.exe /r /o" command. It still boots to the lock screen; I can't get to bios on startup, and UEFI is still unavailable in Settings.  I was in the bios when I got this machine (2 months or so ago) but clearly, something has changed since then.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, after I disabled my aftermarket GPU and enabled my integrated Intel Graphics, I was able to access the BIOS.  Still not entirely sure why that was causing the problem, but I thought I would post this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that if you see the startup options, that it is trying to load the Windows OS, which happens after the BIOS initialisation.

- I can see you [tried to get to it from "advanced startup"](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10) which likely eliminates Windows 10 from the equation (really, you shouln't **need** the OS to get to BIOS, that is a convenience, not a requirement).

So let's go back to working on direct-access for this machine:

```
To get to the BIOS with HP Desktops:
 You need to tap the <ESC> key JUST after pressing the power button on the front.
```

- I can see you have tried combinations of this, but perhaps *just* focus on only <kbd>ESC</kbd> straight after the power button on the tower. If it working, you will then see the 'classic' message on the screen to press the function-key to get to system configuration (BIOS).

  - It could be like DELL machines where you need to **hold** the key **while** pressing the power button. I would try this last though, as [the HP manual](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-750-Desktop-PC-series/8499646/model/8883995/manuals) specifically says to tap <kbd>ESC</kbd> straight after it.

**Other possible causes:**

- Screen isn't turning on in time to display the confirmation message.
- Your keyboard is not compatible with BIOS/UEFI (unlikely, but try another USB port or another Keyboard)
- The BIOS is locked. (also unlikely as windows advanced recovery would have asked for the password on reboot)